# warning: format '%06d' expects type 'int', but argument 5 has type '__suseconds_t'

Tags: c, timeval

I am using this code:

```
struct timeval tv;
time_t nowtime;
struct tm *nowtm;
char tmbuf[64], buf[64];

gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
nowtime = tv.tv_sec;
nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);
strftime(tmbuf, sizeof tmbuf, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", nowtm);
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s.%06d", tmbuf, tv.tv_usec);
```

from this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409054/997112

to print a struct timeval in to a readable format. However, I get this compiler warning:

```
warning: format '%06d' expects type 'int', but argument 5 has type '__suseconds_t'
```

Could somebody please help?

Comment: Quite self explanatory: `tv_usec` member of a `tv` struct is a `__suseconds_t` type. However, this is a typedef of a long, so you can display it with printf as a long number: replace `%06d` by `%06ld`

Comment: @LoveMetal well I wondered why would there be something wrong with an answer with so many upvotes. Is this because of the system I am on?

Comment: Well... I wonder too xD. Try a little cast to `long`, it often solve a problem.

Comment: @LoveMetal it worked! Put as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tv_usec` member of `struct tv` structure is a `__suseconds_t` datatype, which is a typedef to `long`. You can display it with `%06ld` instead of `%06d`.

And it seems like a cast to `long` would be better, at least for portability issues.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler issues a warning because the type expected by printf - `int` is not the same type as the argument - `long` (which is what `__suseconds_t` is). Your code will work on many current systems, whenever `int` and `long` are the same size (either 32 or 64 bits).

As there *are* systems where this is not the case (e.g. int 32 bit, long 64 bits), for better portability, you should cast the value to the actual type `printf` expects:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s.%06ld", tmbuf, (long) tv.tv_usec);
```

As the value of `tv.tv_usec` is always less than a million, on a system with at least 32 bit ints, `"%06d"` and casting to int will also work, but I would prefer staying with long.

Incidentally, the warning points out a problem with all those typedefs that are used these days. I think a relative beginner might have had a better chance at understanding the actual problem if the message had mentioned `long` instead of or in addition to `__suseconds_t`. The clang compiler actually does this: `"'__suseconds_t' (aka 'long')"`.