# snprintf not printing out a converted timeval using strftime?

Tags: c, printf, strftime, timeval

I have taken this answer from SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409054/997112

so that I can print timeval structs in a friendly format. I had to change `"%s.%06d"` for `"%s.%06ld"` because I was getting compiler warnings:

```
void printTimeval(struct timeval& tv){

    time_t nowtime;
    struct tm *nowtm;
    char tmbuf[64], buf[64];

    nowtime = tv.tv_sec;
    nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);

    strftime(tmbuf, sizeof tmbuf, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", nowtm);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s.%06ld", tmbuf, tv.tv_usec);
}
```

However, when I pass a valid time nothing prints.

I checked the number of seconds in the timeval I passed-in, before calling my function and it returns 1404120855, so I am confident my timeval is correct and the problem lies with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `snprintf()` does is format a string. You never actually print out the resulting string in `buf`. Add something like:

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

or

```
puts(buf);
```

Also, you should have a cast to `long` for that `tv_usec` field, since you can't *know* the type of the typedef to be `long`.

Comment: Hi- thanks! Did you mean snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s.%06ld", tmbuf, (long)tv.tv_usec); ?

Comment: @user997112 Yes, that's exactly what I meant.