# Convert timestamp obtained from adb shell getevent to hh:mm:ss.SSS format using java

Tags: java, android, datetime, adb

I am trying to convert the timestamp captured from adb shell getevent by using the following command

```
adb shell getevent -lt /dev/input/event2 >filepath/filename.txt
```

This gives the output like the below

```
  [   19393.303318] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000b87
  [   19393.303318] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000180
  [   19393.303318] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000004e2
  [   19393.303318] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_PRESSURE      0000004c
  [   19393.303318] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000001
  [   19393.303318] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
```

here the timestamp seen is 19393.303318 which is not in normal time format

How to convert it in to hh:mm:ss:SSS format using JAVA

If possible is there any other way to get proper time format for adb shell getevent

Thanks in advance

Comment: @AlexP. is there a way to convert this to time in Java

There is a solution in C which converts timestamp to readable format

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408976/struct-timeval-to-printable-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that the output of getevent is based on the `uptimeMillis()` instead of the `elapsedRealtime()`. Just like the `getEventTime`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputEvent.html#getEventTime().

I use this uptimeMillis get the correct timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like number of seconds since boot. To get absolute timestamp of moment of boot you can use something like this: `System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`.

Comment: I want to convert timestamp to HH:mm:ss format

Comment: Assuming that you have value extracted from output as a `long` (you can use eg. `Scanner` for that). Then you can add it to boot time mentioned above and pass such summed timestamp to `new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date(timestamp))`

Comment: is SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() is a android method ?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()

Comment: No. I want a method in java

Comment: Is there any other way of capturing adb shell getevent along with the time ??

Comment: You can get time since boot also by adb: `adb shell uptime`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer. I think you have to start googling for your queries. I am not good in java, But this took 2 hours for me for search and write this.Not properly arranged anyway this works and now I can use same to convert dmesg to adb shell date format.
 Note:- while replace `date and uptime` use -  `date;cat /proc/uptime` inside adb shell to get both at same time(not fully accurate )

> main method to convert getevent file

```
public static void convertGetEventFiletoHumanReadableTime(
        String geteventFileLocation) throws ParseException, IOException {

    SimpleDateFormat adbDatefmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
    String adbDate = "Mon Jan  4 21:23:19 KST 2016"; //replace with your adb shell date
    String uptime = "33224.56 242604.45" //replace with your device cat adb shell /proc/uptime
    uptime = uptime.split(" ")[0];
    String event = "/dev/input/event1" //replace with event type you need to

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(dmesgFileLocation));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        int lineNum = 0;
        while (line != null) {

            // System.out.println(lineNum + ": " + line); //for debug
            if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                String eventTimeStamp = getEventTimeStamp(line, event);
                System.out.println("TIME " + eventTimeStamp);
                float eventTimeF = Float.parseFloat(eventTimeStamp);
                float eventTimeMillisecF = (float) (Math
                        .round(eventTimeF * 100.0) / 100.0);

                Date dmesghTime = convertGeteventTimestampToHumanReadable(
                        uptime, adbDate, eventTimeMillisecF);
                line = line.replace(eventTimeStamp,
                        adbDatefmt.format(dmesghTime));

                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            line = br.readLine();
            lineNum++;
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        // System.out.println(everything);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/getevent_humanTime.txt", true);
            fw.write(everything);
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Something happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

> method to get event timestamp from each line

```
public static String getEventTimeStamp(String event_string, String pattern) {

    Pattern pTime = Pattern
            .compile("\\[.*(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)\\].*"
                    + pattern);
    Matcher mTime = pTime.matcher(event_string);

    String time = null;
    if (mTime.find()) {
        System.out.println("Time " + mTime.group(1));
        time = mTime.group(1);
    }
    return time;
}
```

> method to convert epoch time to human readable [ round to millisec]

```
public static Date convertGeteventTimestampToHumanReadable(String  uptime,String adbDate , float secTimestamp)
        throws ParseException {


    System.out.println("DEVICE UPTIME IN SECS " + uptime);

    float uptimeMilliSecF = Float.parseFloat(uptime) * 1000;
    int uptimeMilliSec = Float.valueOf(uptimeMilliSecF).intValue();

    int dmesgtimeinMillisec = (int) (secTimestamp * 1000);

    SimpleDateFormat adbDatefmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date date = adbDatefmt.parse(adbDate);
    System.out.println("ADB DATE: " + date);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -uptimeMilliSec);
    System.out.println("ADB DATE AT DEVICE UP: " + calendar.getTime());

    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, dmesgtimeinMillisec);
    System.out.println("ADB DATE FOR DMESG EVENT: " + calendar.getTime());

    return calendar.getTime();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer will see whether this works or not and will get back to you for any questions