# Get millisecond from NTP server

Tags: c, arduino, ntp

Currently I'm trying to create a lap timer using a microcontroller ESP32. I'm thinking of using NTP server `pool.ntp.org` to get a precision timing of several milliseconds.

I tried to do something like this

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "time.h"
String time_str;
time_t epoch;
const char* ssid     = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASSWORD";

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Start_WiFi(ssid,password);
  configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org");
}

void loop() {
  setenv("TZ", "  WIB-7", 1);
  Serial.println("  Jakarta Time  = "+printLocalTime());
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);
}

String printLocalTime(){
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return "Time Error";
  }
  char output[80];
  //epoch = mktime(&timeinfo);
  //return epoch;
  strftime(output, 80, "%d-%b-%y, %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
  time_str = String(output);
  return time_str;
}

int Start_WiFi(const char* ssid, const char* password){
  int connAttempts = 0;
  Serial.println("\r\nConnecting to: "+String(ssid));
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    if(connAttempts > 20) return -5;
    connAttempts++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I would like to get millisecond precision from `struct tm timeinfo`. I tried to use `strftime` and `mktime` but i realise that both `strftime` and `mktime` returns only up to second.

Comment: Why don't you convert it to milliseconds?

Comment: Not sure where you use NTP in this example. Anyway, you might be able to use `gettimeofday()` with `struct timeval` which has a tv_nsec member.

Comment: sorry, i'll add up some more of my code details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are using the struct

```
struct tm
{
  int   tm_sec;
  int   tm_min;
  int   tm_hour;
  int   tm_mday;
  int   tm_mon;
  int   tm_year;
  int   tm_wday;
  int   tm_yday;
  int   tm_isdst;
#ifdef __TM_GMTOFF
  long  __TM_GMTOFF;
#endif
#ifdef __TM_ZONE
  const char *__TM_ZONE;
#endif
};
```

from [arduino-esp32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/newlib/time.h).

Because in this struct the smalles resolution is seconds.
Why not using one of the integrated timers?

Comment: Yes sys/time.h with timeval is better: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/newlib/sys/time.h

Comment: I never know that there's another library. Sorry, I'm new to microcontroller programming. I'll try to use sys/time.h and update the results ASAP

Comment: In that case it’s C not related to microcontrollers. You will need to format the nanoseconds yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469495/unix-programming-struct-timeval-how-to-print-it-c-programming

Comment: @eckes is there any similar function to getLocalTime for timeval type?

Comment: `gettimeofday()` fills this structure